# modify overlay on video previews in the Explorer sidebar

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-explorer, themes, desktop-customization

I want to get rid of the stupid overlays that video files are shown with in the Explorer sidebar in Windows (7, but other versions as well). I mean thanks, but 1995 rang and they want their UI design back: my video file is not a piece of celluloid, and I don't need fake sprocket holes to tell me it's a movie.

Anyone have any idea of where this overlay lives and how to nuke it?

[image: Ugly! Ugly! Ugly!]